# Call removeFile in for-loop

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

In a dropzone.js, I have a script to create multiple folders, and this works with 2 actions, after a button (so autoprocessqueue is false).

The first action is to create the right database-entry, and create the folder. This returns an object with the Foldername, and the UUID from the database.
If this fails, the Foldername gets the value `false` instead of the UUID.

Then I process my dropzone.getQueuedFiles to remove files where the folder has not been created.

However in this for-loop not every file is deleted, but only some of it.

```js
document.getElementById('CreateBundelButton').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    axios.post(uploadConfig.multibundelUploadUrl + collectie.uuid + '/', { collectie : collectie , isBundelCreateAndCheck : true , folders : BundelFolders })
                    .then( response => { 
         console.log("Received UUIDs")
         for(let fList = 0 ; fList < dropzone.getQueuedFiles().length ; fList++) {
             let rootFolder = (dropzone.getQueuedFiles()[fList].fullPath).split('/')[0]
             if(response.data.uuidList[rootFolder] !== false) { 
                  //set folder-view as created 
             } else {  
                  dropzone.removeFile(dropzone.getQueuedFiles()[fList]) 
             }
         }
         //setAutoProcessDropzone(true)
         //dropzone.processQueue()
    }
}
```

So when I click the button, not every file from the folder where response.data.uuidList[rootFolder] = false get removed.

Update: everytime only half of the files are removed from the queue. So a folder with 100 files, 50 are removed, a folder with 10, 5 are removed.

Comment: Better to store value in a variable. You can do  ` let files = dropzone.getQueuedFiles()` and all the working will be use as `files.length` and `files[fList]`.

Comment: Thanks! This did indeed solve the problem.